# My Balance States Throws Balance.map is not a function error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a simple React app that keeps track of expenses, income, and balances. I'm using a state hook called Balance that is the sum of all the input state. The issue is React throws a Balance.map is not a function. So, I'm unable to show what the total would be when the user enters all their input.

Here's the full code:

```
export default function App() {
  const [Balance, setBalance] = useState([]);
  const [Income, setIncome] = useState(0);
  const [Expense, setExpense] = useState(0);

  const [Input, setInput] = useState([]);

  console.log(typeof Balance);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (Input > 0) {
      setIncome(Input);
    } else {
      setExpense(Input);
    }
    let val = parseInt(Input);
    setBalance(val, ...Balance);

    //console.log(...Balance);
    setInput("");
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ textAlign: "center", marginTop: "150px" }}>
      <form>
        <label htmlFor="input"> Please enter value: </label>
        <input
          name="input"
          type="number"
          value={Input}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <button onClick={handleClick}> Submit</button>
      </form>
      <br />
      <h3> My Balance:</h3>
      <p>
        {Balance.map((i) => {
          return i;
        })}
      </p>
      <h3> My Income: {Income}</h3>
      <h3> My Expense: {Expense}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I know that the Balance state ,despite it being set as an array, is still an object. I'm assuming the error is coming from there? If so, should setBalance(...Input) work?

Comment: `map` only works on arrays, if you want to set balance to an object it won't work

Comment: Right, I believe I set it to an array like this : `const [Balance, setBalance] = useState([]);`

Comment: but you changed to something else here: `setBalance(val, ...Balance);` not sure what type you want but this doesn't look like an object or array

Comment: I see, I was trying to make sure Balance holds all values that the user submits and will submit. I tried this `setBalance(Input)`. Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: You should try something like `setBalance(Balance.concat(Input))`, and you initial state of `Input` should be a blank string `const [Input, setInput] = useState('');` instead of an blank array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as users say in the comments, the problem is the way you update the value of Balance, [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-babbage-g036w?file=/src/App.js:521-586) I do some changes in this places:

```js
let val = parseInt(Input, 10); // Here I add the base of parseInt

setBalance([...Balance, val]) Here I let the value as an array in the setBalance
```

The complete code is:

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [Balance, setBalance] = useState([]);
  const [Income, setIncome] = useState(0);
  const [Expense, setExpense] = useState(0);

  const [Input, setInput] = useState([]);

  console.log(typeof Balance);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (Input > 0) {
      setIncome(Input);
    } else {
      setExpense(Input);
    }
    let val = parseInt(Input, 10);
    setBalance([...Balance, val]);

    //console.log(...Balance);
    setInput("");
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ textAlign: "center", marginTop: "150px" }}>
      <form>
        <label htmlFor="input"> Please enter value: </label>
        <input
          name="input"
          type="number"
          value={Input}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <button onClick={handleClick}> Submit</button>
      </form>
      <br />
      <h3> My Balance:</h3>
      <p>
        {Balance.map((i) => {
          return i;
        })}
      </p>
      <h3> My Income: {Income}</h3>
      <h3> My Expense: {Expense}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing your insight. Out of curiosity, how does `setBalance([...Balance, val])` work? I understand that setBalance will take all elements of the current array and the new value inputted. However, why would that work as oppose to setBalance([10])?

Comment: with setBalance([10]) you delete all the existing values in the array and just add 10, with the spread operator setBalance([...Balance, val]), you add a new value to the array.

Comment: @traveler316 the `[...Balance, val]` part means to build an array (the `[]` symbol), `...Balance` means to iterate `Balance` and copy all its value. so say if you have `Balance = [1, 2]` and `val = 3`, `[...Balance, val]` means `[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: @OscarVelandia Thanks for providing clarity on this.